# How to remove unwanted space after image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a image which has a text on it and a button on it. When hovered on image text and button should appear and a border inside the image should animate.

The red color part in the snippet is the problem for me. Here, I want to an image and on that image a text and a button but when I move `.box-content` which contains text and button on the image, it moves but leaves an unwanted space. I also tried doing `.box` to height of `320px` and changing `bottom` accordingly and it worked but not in other screen like `1024x768` (responsive).

Note:- I am also using bootstrap for this.

I just want to remove that unwanted space at bottom (red color part after moving).

```css
.evc-banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.box .box-content {
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover .box-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="evc-banner">
  <div class="box col-3">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-design-oxygen-tank-illustration_23-2149499403.jpg?t=st=1694436592~exp=1694437192~hmac=4226fcd174f7ed1cb6f7f98ef67158102add52d0a7b867974aa1650649ae7fa4" alt="">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h1>High Quality</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-info">Shop</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box col-3">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-design-oxygen-tank-illustration_23-2149499403.jpg?t=st=1694436592~exp=1694437192~hmac=4226fcd174f7ed1cb6f7f98ef67158102add52d0a7b867974aa1650649ae7fa4" alt="">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h1>Great Prices</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-info">Shop</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box col-3">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-design-oxygen-tank-illustration_23-2149499403.jpg?t=st=1694436592~exp=1694437192~hmac=4226fcd174f7ed1cb6f7f98ef67158102add52d0a7b867974aa1650649ae7fa4" alt="">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h1>Big Brand</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-info">Shop</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```